# Git commit naming when conflict. Does it right?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I have two branches: `master` and `feature`

On `master` I have changed version to 19 and on `feature` I have changed version to 9 (yeah, this is old branch). I want to refresh it so:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

And I get conflict:

```
git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines lib/XXX/Schema.pm
diff --cc lib/XXX/Schema.pm
index 0922bb2,344f0e1..0000000
--- a/lib/XXX/Schema.pm
+++ b/lib/XXX/Schema.pm
@@@ -1,6 -1,6 +1,12 @@@
  package XXX::Schema;

++<<<<<<< ours
 +our $VERSION =  19;
++||||||| base
++our $VERSION =  8;
++=======
+ our $VERSION =  9;
++>>>>>>> theirs


  use strict;
```

Because of I am on `feature` branch I count it as `OURS` and changes on `master` branch as `THEIRS`. Right?

Why my local changes are displayed as `>>>>>> theirs` is merge conflict?

Comment: Are you asking why "ours" and "theirs" are used to refer to the branches they do, or why the difference in value for `VERSION` is considered a conflict?

Comment: @chepner `why "ours" and "theirs" are used to refer to the branches they do`. I expect there should be `>>>>>>> ours` because `9` was introduced on branch I am currently on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a fall-out of how `rebase` works. It resets to the commit you rebase onto, i.e., `master`, and then cherry-picks the commits from the `feature` branch. Therefore, the changes being rebased (the `feature` branch) are *theirs*, and the changes on the `master` branch are *ours*.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this process as re applying commits from `feature` to `feature'`